# How change border color of text box when text box empty Lost focus event and onfocus event if text not empty then dont change border color

Tags: jquery

I want to change text box's border color if text box is empty, using events.

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#name1").onFocus(function () {
        if ($("#name1").val() == "") $(this).css({
            "border": "red",
        });
        $("#name1").LostFocus(function () {
            if ($("#name1").val() != "") $(this).css({
                "border": "",
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="">
    <input id="name1" type="textbox"></input>
    <input id="name2" type="textbox"></input>
    <input id="name3" type="textbox"></input>
    <input type="button" value="submit"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: try `focus` instead of `onFocus` and use `blur` for `LostFocus`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

see live [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JuGt4/4/)

**HTML**

```
<form action=""> 
    <input id ="name1" type="textbox"></input>
    <input id ="name2" type="textbox"></input>
    <input id ="name3" type="textbox"></input>
    <input type="button" value="submit"></input>
</form>
```

**css**

```
.red {
     border-color:red;   
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").focusin(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "")
        $(this).addClass("red")
    });
    $("input").focusout(function(){
        if ($(this).val() != "")
        $(this).removeClass("red")
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this by using **blur**

```
 $("input[type='textbox']").blur(function () {
    var text = $(this).val();
    if(text == "")
    {
        $(this).css('border-color','red');
    }
    });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aCz7E/

Answer (score 0):

try `focus` instead of `onFocus` and use `blur` for `LostFocus`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#name1").focus(function(){
if ($("#name1").val() == "")
$(this).css({
"border": "red",
});

$("#name1").blur(function(){

if ($("#name1").val() != "")
$(this).css({
"border": "",
});


});
});
```

Read more: http://api.jquery.com/focus/ and http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Answer (score 0):

use a custom onChange handler: <kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/YtvVU/)</kbd>

```
$(function () {
    $("#name1").on("change", function () {
        if($(this).val()==""){
            $(this).css({
                "border":"2px solid red"
            });
        }
        else{
            $(this).css({
                "border":""
            });
        }
    });
});
```